# Postgresql golang sqlx package query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I am using golang sqlx package and postgresql as the database. I have two simple tables

```
create table items (
    id varchar unique primary key not null,
    is_active bool not null default false
);

create table images (
    item_id varchar not null,
    link varchar unique not null,
    index int not null,
    foreign key (item_id) references items(id) on delete cascade
);
```

What I need to perform is to get all of the items that have assigned images to them in one query and do not manipulate with go variables afterwards

I have such code in order to perform that

```
type Image struct {
    ItemID string `db:"item_id" json:"item_id"`
    Index int `db:"index" json:"index"`
    Link string `db:"link" json:"link"`
}

type Images []Image

func (t Images) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(t); if err != nil {
        return driver.Value(""), err
    }
    return driver.Value(string(b)), nil
}

func (t *Images) Scan (src interface{}) error {
    var source []byte

    if reflect.TypeOf(src) == nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch src.(type) {
        case string:
            source = []byte(src.(string))
        case []byte:
            source = src.([]byte)
        default:
            return errors.New("incompatible type for images")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(source, t)
}

func GetItems (active bool) (items []Item, err error) {
    conn := postgres.Connection()

    const query = `SELECT *, (
        SELECT json_agg(images) AS images FROM (
            SELECT images.link, images.index FROM images GROUP BY images.link, images.index HAVING bool_or(item_id=items.id) AND count(item_id) > 0
        ) as images
    ) FROM items`

    if err := conn.Select(&items, query, active); err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Errorf("Can not get all items")
    }

    return
}

This works but I can have results with items that has no assigned images for them and this code seems tooo complicated for such simple at first sight task. Wish anyone can help me with that
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wanna do this:

```
select i.id 
from images img
join items i 
 on img.item_id = i.id
where i.isactive =1 
group by i.id
```

Comment: yes that is very helpful but I need to get not only the ids. Like I need to load values from table images to struct Images inside struct Items

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output then, ok I see you figured it out , give this answer upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @eshirvana I came to this solution:

```
SELECT items.*, json_agg(images) as images 
FROM items 
JOIN images 
   ON images.item_id = items.id 
WHERE is_active=$1 
GROUP BY items.id
```